# Getting error as Mysql: command not found

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I am running `lampp` on linux and trying to access `Mysql` using command line, but getting error as `-bash: mysql: command not found`

[image]

Comment: Could you copy/paste the lines instead of using an image, to improve readibility? Could you connect to MySQL using ther tools (workbench, eg)?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen: i am able to access using PHPMyAdmin, but not using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've not installed MySQL [command line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html). In 16.04 the client can be found from package `mysql-client-core-5.7`.